# Ruby count hash key

Tags: ruby

I have a hash like this:

```
{'yes' => 23,
 'b' => 'travel',
 'yesterday' => 34,
 5 => '234',
 :yesss => :fg,
 try: 30,
 key: 'some value',
 'yesterday1' => 34,
 'yesteryear' => 2014}
```

How can I count all keys which includes `yes`?

Comment: Can you rephrase it in plain english ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We'd like to see evidence of your effort toward solving the problem. Without that it looks like you're asking us to write code for you, rather than help correct your code which isn't working. SO isn't a "write code for me site" so it's important to show us what you tried. Please read "[ask]" including the links, and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suppose you meant:

```
your_hash.count { |k, _| k.to_s.include?('yes') }
#=> 5
```